# VB .Net Different Arithmetic Result in Two Apps

Tags: vb.net, formula, arithmetic-expressions

i have a compiled Vb .Net Program that have below Arithmetic line when i want to use this line
in new App has different result
the code is :

```
Protected Sub MethodOne(ByRef A_1 As UInteger,A_2 As UInteger,A_3 As UInteger,A_4 As UInteger,A_5 As UInteger,A_6 As UShort,A_7 As UInteger)
A_1 = A_2 + Class2.Method1(A_1 + ((A_2 And A_3) Or (Not A_2 And A_4)) + 127, A_6)
    End Sub
```

'==================================== method  in Class2 difinition ====================

```
        Public Shared Function Method1(A_0 As UInteger, A_1 As UShort) As UInteger
                          Return A_0 >> CInt((32US - A_1)) Or A_0 << CInt(A_1)
        End Function
```

=================================================

with predefined values as

A_1 = 1732584193UI

A_2 = 4023233417UI

A_3 = 2562383102UI

A_4 = 271733878UI

A_5 = 0

A_6 = 7

A_7 = 0

when i Call MethodOne in Compiled App the Result of MethodOne is

```
    A_1 2770347892  uint
```

but when i Run Same Code in New App With Same A_1 to A_7 Values the Result is

```
    A_1 4023249673  uint
```

notice : in both Assembly i have turned on **RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute:WrapNonExceptionThrows=true**

What i have mistake ?

regards

Comment: "With Same A_1 to A_4 Values"... but `MethodOne` has other parameters, A_5 to A_7, which affect the calculation (well, A_6 does anyway).  Are those input values different between your two apps?  Or was this just a typo in your question, and you meant to say "With Same A_1 to A_7 Values"?

Comment: oh Sorry  A_5 = 0 , A_6=7 , A_7=1

Comment: Have you tried stepping through both apps in the debugger to see where they diverge?

Comment: @craig of course in old App MethodOne Send this expression
A_1 + ((A_2 And A_3) Or (Not A_2 And A_4)) + 127
 as "3614090487"
but in new project just send "127" 
i think that's must related to something about integer Arithmetic in compiler
i should mention that in both project i turn off integer overflow in compile option in project properties

Comment: If you're stepping through in the debugger, then the next thing I'd suggest to do is try putting a watch on subexpressions (or even assign them to variables).  You may be able to find a specific piece that contributes to the overall difference.  (e.g. check `A_2 And A_3` in both to make sure that's the same, check `Not A_2 And A_4`, then check results of both `Or`ed together, etc.)

Comment: RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute:WrapNonExceptionThrows=true? That wraps thrown objects that do not inherit from exception and has nothing to do with arithmetic overflow checks.

Comment: Your calculation results in 4023249545 on my machine. But I suspect something is wrong with your formula anyway as argument 7 is not used at all, as I get an OverflowException if I do not explicitly suppress it and was forced to add an explicit cast from Int64 to UInt32 to get it running.

Comment: i'v  turnd on "overflow check" in compile tab of project properties

Answer (score 0):

that's all my fault
in MethodOne " number 127 callback from an array
thus i'v have to find the array what number callback
anyway
appreciate for your helps